# How to zero out memory allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal?

Tags: .net, memory, unmanaged-memory

I am allocating some unmanaged memory in my application via `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.  I'm then copying a set of bytes to this location and converting the resulting segment of memory to a `struct` before freeing the memory again via `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Here's the method:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] messageBytes, int start, int length)
    where T : struct
{
    if (start + length > messageBytes.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    int typeSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    int bytesToCopy = Math.Min(typeSize, length);

    IntPtr targetBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(typeSize);
    Marshal.Copy(messageBytes, start, targetBytes, bytesToCopy);

    if (length < typeSize)
    {
        // Zero out additional bytes at the end of the struct
    }

    T item = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(targetBytes, typeof(T));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(targetBytes);
    return item;
}
```

This works for the most part, however if I have fewer bytes than the size of the `struct` requires, then 'random' values are assigned to the last fields (I am using `LayoutKind.Sequential` on the target struct).  I'd like to zero out these hanging fields as efficiently as possible.

For context, this code is deserializing high-frequency multicast messages sent from C++ on Linux.

Here is a failing test case:

```
// Give only one byte, which is too few for the struct
var s3 = MessageSerializer.Deserialize<S3>(new[] { (byte)0x21 });
Assert.AreEqual(0x21, s3.Byte);
Assert.AreEqual(0x0000, s3.Int); // hanging field should be zero, but isn't

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
private struct S3
{
    public byte Byte;
    public int Int;
}
```

Running this test repeatedly causes the second assert to fail with a different value each time.

---

**EDIT**

In the end, I used [leppie's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486999/how-to-zero-out-memory-allocated-by-marshal-allochglobal/1487056#1487056) of going `unsafe` and using `stackalloc`.  This allocated a byte array that was zeroed as needed, and improved throughput from between 50% and 100%, depending upon the message size (larger messages saw greater benefit).

The final method ended up resembling:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] messageBytes, int startIndex, int length)
    where T : struct
{
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", length, "Must be greater than zero.");
    if (startIndex < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", startIndex, "Must be greater than or equal to zero.");
    if (startIndex + length > messageBytes.Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", length, "startIndex + length must be <= messageBytes.Length");

    int typeSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    unsafe
    {
        byte* basePtr = stackalloc byte[typeSize];
        byte* b = basePtr;
        int end = startIndex + Math.Min(length, typeSize);
        for (int srcPos = startIndex; srcPos < end; srcPos++)
            *b++ = messageBytes[srcPos];
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(basePtr), typeof(T));
    }   
}
```

Unfortunately this still requires a call to `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to convert the bytes into the target type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just check whether `start + length` is within `typesize`?

BTW: I would just go `unsafe` here and use a for loop to to zero out the additional memory.

That too will give you the benefit of using `stackalloc` which is much safer and faster than `AllocGlobal`.

Comment: @leppie -- thanks for the useful info.  I'll check out `stackalloc` too.  I have to cater for differing message sizes as the two teams can occasionally manage to avoid synchronised releases if we add fields on the end that the other end ignores.  Similarly, if you don't require values, you can expect them and get zeroes instead, which is the case I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: @leppie, I'm leaning towards this approach.  Could you go into some more detail as to _why_ using `stackalloc` is safer and faster?  Once I have the `byte*`, what would be the best way to copy into it?

Comment: I've put together a version that works with `stackalloc` to populate an array on the stack.  I don't think it's possible to get around the call to `Marshal.PtrToStructure` though, is it?

Comment: @Drew: Nah, I also didnt realize generics sucked so hard when going unsafe  :(  If your types are known, you could generate all the 'templates'.  That would keep it fast.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a generic API that will deal with unknown and varied types (though all of fixed size.)

Answer (score 20):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void RtlZeroMemory(IntPtr dst, UIntPtr length);
...
RtlZeroMemory(targetBytes, typeSize);
```

Comment: Dumpbin.exe on kernel32.dll says it isn't just a macro.

Comment: @MattiasS -- I need to zero out at `dst + N`.  `IntPtr` doesn't support arithmetic, so how can I address this offset?

Comment: Can't you simply zero out the entire buffer before the Marshal.Copy call? That way, whatever part you don't overwrite with the struct will remain zero. You can do arithmetic on the pointer value if you cast it to a long and then back to IntPtr.

Comment: The second parameter should be `IntPtr` instead of `int` I think.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. There is no reason to use anything else. In windows.h this is a macro simply for code interoperability. The NtosKrnl version claims to be platform specific, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563610(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @SimonMourier: When the second parameter is `IntPtr` then we could zero more than 2 GB. Did you tried it out?

Comment: @Wollmich - yes, in a 64-bit process, but I never tried it.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Net Core or NET5, you can now call [Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.initblockunaligned?view=netcore-3.1):

```
Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned((byte*)ptr, 0, byteCount)
```

For anything but trivial data sizes, this is order of magnitude faster than doing the pointer loop manually, as it uses platform specific intrinsic for full hardware acceleration. You get benefit of kernel32 solution, but cross platform and without need for managing native dependencies manually.

Answer (score 6):

This will work fine on Windows:

```
namespace KernelPInvoke
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements some of the C functions declared in string.h
    /// </summary>
    public static class MemoryWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
        static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, uint length);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "MoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
        static extern void MoveMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, uint length);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlFillMemory", SetLastError = false)]
        static extern void FillMemory(IntPtr destination, uint length, byte fill);
    }

    var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    try
    {
        MemoryWrapper.FillMemory(ptr, size, 0);
        // further work...
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes as [Jon Seigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164901/jon-seigel) said, you can zero it out using Marshal.WriteByte

In the following example, I zero out the buffer before copying the struct.

```
if (start + length > messageBytes.Length) 
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();   
int typeSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));    
int bytesToCopy = Math.Min(typeSize, length);   
IntPtr targetBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(typeSize);  
//zero out buffer
for(int i=0; i < typeSize; i++)
{
    Marshal.WriteByte(targetBytes, i, 0);
}
Marshal.Copy(messageBytes, start, targetBytes, bytesToCopy);
```

Comment: Each call to Marshal.WriteByte will cause a transition between managed and native code and back, which has a certain overhead. Doing that in a loop can get inefficient. If you want to stick to the Marshal class, I'd try this instead: Marshal.Copy(new byte[typeSize], 0, targetBytes, typeSize)

Comment: The other alternative I was thinking of was P/Invoke the LocalAlloc function and pass in the LPTR flag.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done this stuff in C# before, but I found Marshal.WriteByte(IntPtr, Int32, Byte) in MSDN. Try that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0; i < buffSize / 8; i += 8 )
{
    Marshal.WriteInt64(buffer, i, 0x00);
}

for(int i= buffSize % 8 ; i < -1 ; i-- )
{
    Marshal.WriteByte (buffer, buffSize - i, 0x00);
}
```

I think you will find it to be several times faster using 64 bit writes instead of 8 bit writes (which you still need for the last few bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to zero out a buffer is this, if you don't want, or can't go the other way:

```
for(int i=0; i<buffSize; i++)
{
    Marshal.WriteByte(buffer, i, 0x00);
}
```