# C# Marshal.Copy Intptr to 16 bit managed unsigned integer array

Tags: c#, marshalling

Why does C# Marshal.Copy routine does not have any overload for copying from unmanaged memory pointer to 16 bit managed unsigned integer array?

ex:

```
Copy(IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)  Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 8-bit unsigned integer array.
Copy(IntPtr, Char[], Int32, Int32)  Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed character array.
Copy(IntPtr, Double[], Int32, Int32)    Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed double-precision floating-point number array.
Copy(IntPtr, Int16[], Int32, Int32) Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 16-bit signed integer array.
Copy(IntPtr, Int32[], Int32, Int32) Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 32-bit signed integer array.
Copy(IntPtr, Int64[], Int32, Int32) Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed 64-bit signed integer array.
Copy(IntPtr, IntPtr[], Int32, Int32)    Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed IntPtr array.
Copy(IntPtr, Single[], Int32, Int32).   Copies data from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed single-precision floating-point number array.
```

If there is no marshalling alternative, how do I copy unmanaged ushort array to managed ushort array?

Comment: 8 years later and all these answers are still unsatisfying and either don't work or are ridiculously inefficient. (vs. just copy in a loop).  :(

Comment: <Span> might be your best bet now.

Answer (score 3):

Using unsafe code:

```
public static unsafe void Copy(IntPtr ptrSource, ushort[] dest, uint elements) {
  fixed(ushort* ptrDest = &dest[0]) {
     CopyMemory((IntPtr)ptrDest, ptrSource, elements * 2);    // 2 bytes per element
  }
}

public static unsafe void Copy(ushort[] source, Intptr ptrDest, uint elements) {
  fixed(ushort* ptrSource = &source[0]) {
     CopyMemory(ptrDest, (Intptr)ptrSource, elements * 2);    // 2 bytes per element
  }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr Destination, IntPtr Source, uint Length);
```

Can be easily adapted to copy uint[] and ulong[] (adjust the number of bytes per element)

Comment: Just a note that `CopyMemory()` is basically a macro alias for `memcpy()` (AFAICT) so it one is using C++/CLI then using `memcpy` (or `memcpy_s`) would be quicker and easier.  I know the question didn't specify C++/CLI but that how I got here. In either case, mem-copying into a managed array (using `pin_ptr` if in C++/CLI) is the only thing that seems to work and I guess is relatively efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** `Marshal` doesn't have a `Copy(IntPtr, UInt16[], Int32, Int32)` overload because of CLS compliance (a tenet of CLS compliance is that the integer types `SByte`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, and `UInt64` are not exposed to consumers because they aren't supported by the broader gamut of CLR-compatible languages <sub>- and it's hardly rare: even in 2022 [Java still doesn't have unsigned types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430346/why-doesnt-java-support-unsigned-ints)</sub>.

With marshalling integer arrays, all that matters is the size of the elements, not their signed-ness - this also goes for `Array.BlockCopy` - so I would either use the `Byte` or `Int16` overloads and do my own casting afterwards, or I would use pointers if `unsafe` is allowed.

**Update for .NET Core and later**:

In .NET 6 (and likely .NET Core too) [the `Marshal.Copy` method's implementation is just this](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs):

```cs
private static unsafe void CopyToManaged<T>(IntPtr source, T[] destination, int startIndex, int length)
{
    if (source == IntPtr.Zero) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (destination is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
    if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex);
    if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum);

    void*   sourcePtr = (void*)source;
    Span<T> srcSpan   = new Span<T>(sourcePtr, length);
    Span<T> destSpan  = new Span<T>(destination, startIndex, length);

    srcSpan.CopyTo(destSpan);
}
```

So you could call-into this method using reflection, or just copy+paste it yourself.

**If you can't use `unsafe` or .NET Core... try type-punning:**

I wrote and tested this just now and it runs without issues on .NET Framework 4.8, .NET Core 3.1, and .NET 6, phew:

...but don't go using type-punning everywhere, it's only safe or workable in certain situations like these:

```cs
void Main()
{
    // i.e. `calloc( 0x1000, 2 )`
    IntPtr nativeArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( cb: 0x1000 * sizeof(UInt16) ); // 2KiB == 2048 bytes == 1024 shorts.
    {
        // TODO: Zero-out `nativeArray`, and all memory returned from `AllocHGlobal`, but it's fiddly, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486999/how-to-zero-out-memory-allocated-by-marshal-allochglobal
    }
    
    UInt16[] u16Array = new UInt16[ 0x1000 ];
    
    // Fill the array with incrementing numbers so we can ensure it's copied correctly:
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < u16Array.Length; i++ ) u16Array[i] = (UInt16)(( Int16.MaxValue - 500 ) + i); // `( 32767 - 500 ) + n` ==> [ 32267, 32267, ..., 33267 ] which is between Int16.MaxValue and UInt16.MaxValue.
    
    // Very-self documenting code:
    ThisStructPunsTypes s = new ThisStructPunsTypes( u16Array );

    Int16[] staticTypeInt16RealTypeUInt16 = s.AsInt16;
    
    // Proof of Magic:
    Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( u16Array, staticTypeInt16RealTypeUInt16 ) == true, message: "These two array references, of different types, reference the same single underlying UInt16[]." );
    
    // Copy values from `u16Array` into `nativeArray` using type-punning:
    {
        Marshal.Copy( source: s.AsInt16, startIndex: 0, destination: nativeArray, length: 0x1000 );
    }
    
    // Get the values back out directly into a new (separate) Int16[] buffer:
    Int16[] outputInt16Array;
    {
        outputInt16Array = new Int16[ 0x1000 ];
        Marshal.Copy( source: nativeArray, destination: outputInt16Array, startIndex: 0, length: 0x1000 );
    }
    
    // Get the values back out directly into a new (separate) UInt16[] buffer via type-punning:
    UInt16[] outputUInt16Array;
    {
        outputUInt16Array = new UInt16[ 0x1000 ];
        
        ThisStructPunsTypes again = new ThisStructPunsTypes( outputUInt16Array );
        
        Int16[] typePunAgain = again.AsInt16;
        
        Marshal.Copy( source: nativeArray, destination: typePunAgain, startIndex: 0, length: 0x1000 );
    }
    
    
    Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( u16Array, outputInt16Array ) != true, message: "These are two separate array objects." );
    Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( outputInt16Array, outputUInt16Array ) != true, message: "These are two separate array objects." );

    // Observe the values are copied fine from a UInt16 array into native memory, then into a separate and new Int16 array:
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[   0] ==  32267 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[   1] ==  32268 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[   2] ==  32269 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[ 499] ==  32766 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[ 500] ==  32767 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[ 501] == -32768 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[ 502] == -32767 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array[4095] == -29174 );
    Debug.Assert( outputInt16Array.Length == 4096 );
    
    // Observe the values are copied fine from a UInt16 array into native memory, then into a separate and new UInt16 array:
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[   0] ==  32267 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[   1] ==  32268 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[   2] ==  32269 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[ 499] ==  32766 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[ 500] ==  32767 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[ 501] ==  32768 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[ 502] ==  32769 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array[4095] ==  36362 );
    Debug.Assert( outputUInt16Array.Length == 4096 );
}

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
readonly struct ThisStructPunsTypes
{
    public ThisStructPunsTypes( UInt16[] uint16Array )
    {
        this.AsInt16  = default!;
        this.AsUInt16 = uint16Array ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uint16Array));
    }
    
    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public readonly Int16[]  AsInt16;
    
    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public readonly UInt16[] AsUInt16;
}
```

**Slow, but safe, way**:

If you want something that *just works* and assuming you're not bothered about having a temporary second copy of the data then this would work:

```cs
static UInt16[] GetUInt16Array( IntPtr unmanagedArray, Int32 count )
{
    if( unmanagedArray == default ) throw new ArgumentException( ... );
    if( count < 0 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( ... );

    //

    Int16[] signedInt16Array = new Int16[ count ];
    Marshal.Copy( source: unmanagedArray, destination: signedInt16Array, startIndex: 0, length: count );

    Int16[] outputUnsignedInt16Array = new UInt16[ count ];
    Array.Copy( sourceArray: signedInt16Array, destinationArray: outputUnsignedInt16Array, length: count );
    return outputUnsignedInt16Array;
}
```

Comment: This removes all data, since it is all <short> and not <ushort> see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595903/copy-from-intptr-16-bit-array-to-managed-ushort

Comment: Linq, really? It would be much faster to just loop over the unmanaged array and copy the data piecemeal.

Comment: @MaximPaperno That's outside the scope of the OP's question. It's in my answer's code just for illustrative effect - and if anyone is going to copy-and-paste this answer then they've got bigger things to worry about than just a call to `.ToArray`. (Also, I realise my answer is incorrect w.r.t. `OfType`, I'll fix that now).

Comment: Removed, since you removed any Linq reference... :)  Linq is like a slow old dog with a lot of tricks.  `Span` looks promising, as others have suggested.  But really this needs to be benchmarked to see if any of it is worth doing vs. just a loop copy (which, essentially is what any memcopy-like operation does also, though _maybe_ some implementations are optimized for certain situations). The `CopyMemory` hack is likely still most performant (or just `memcpy` from CLI). Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Probably because not all managed languages have unsigned types. I don't think that is a good reason, but it's a reasonable explanation.

A cast should work before the unsigned array parameter.

```
Copy(addr, (Int16[])someUnsignedArray, 0, len);
```

Comment: VB.NET does have unsigned type support, you just need to specify the type-name rather than the language alias, e.g. `Dim foo As UInt16`.

Comment: @dai Ok, I'll remove that from my answer.

Comment: (Int16[]) gives a type conversion error. Here is what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595903/copy-from-intptr-16-bit-array-to-managed-ushort

Comment: That should have worked.... https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/16176#issuecomment-594742104