# Copy from IntPtr (16 bit) array to managed ushort

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `IntPtr` called rawbits, which points to a 10MB array of data, 16 bit values. I need to return a managed `ushort` array from that. The following code works but there is an extra `BlockCopy` I would like to get rid of. `Marshal.Copy` does not support `ushort`. What can I do? (FYI: the rawbits is filled in by a video framegrabber card into unmanaged memory)

```
    public const int width = 2056;
    public const int height = 2048;
    public const int depth = 2;
    public System.IntPtr rawbits;

public ushort[] bits()
{
    ushort[] output = new ushort[width * height];
    short[] temp = new short[width * height];
    Marshal.Copy(rawbits, temp, 0, width * height);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(temp, 0, output, 0, width * height * depth);
    return output;
}
```

The suggestions given in the following question did not help. (compiler error).

[C# Marshal.Copy Intptr to 16 bit managed unsigned integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981551/c-sharp-marshal-copy-intptr-to-16-bit-managed-unsigned-integer-array)

[BTW, the short array does have unsigned 16 bit data in it. The `Marshal.Copy()` does not respect the sign, and that is what I want. But I would rather not just pretend that the `short[]` is a `ushort[]` ]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Option 1 - call `CopyMemory`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, UIntPtr length);

public static void Copy<T>(IntPtr source, T[] destination, int startIndex, int length)
    where T : struct
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(destination, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        var targetPtr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(destination, startIndex);
        var bytesToCopy = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * length;

        CopyMemory(targetPtr, source, (UIntPtr)bytesToCopy);
    }
    finally
    {
        gch.Free();
    }
}
```

Not portable, but has nice performance.

---

Option 2 - `unsafe` and pointers:

```
public static void Copy(IntPtr source, ushort[] destination, int startIndex, int length)
{
    unsafe
    {
        var sourcePtr = (ushort*)source;
        for(int i = startIndex; i < startIndex + length; ++i)
        {
            destination[i] = *sourcePtr++;
        }
    }
}
```

Requires `unsafe` option to be enabled in project build properties.

---

Option 3 - reflection (just for fun, **don't use in production**):

`Marshal` class internally uses `CopyToManaged(IntPtr, object, int, int)` method for all `Copy(IntPtr, <array>, int, int)` overloads (at least in .NET 4.5). Using reflection we can call that method directly:

```
private static readonly Action<IntPtr, object, int, int> _copyToManaged =
    GetCopyToManagedMethod();

private static Action<IntPtr, object, int, int> GetCopyToManagedMethod()
{
    var method = typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("CopyToManaged",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (Action<IntPtr, object, int, int>)method.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Action<IntPtr, object, int, int>), null);
}

public static void Copy<T>(IntPtr source, T[] destination, int startIndex, int length)
    where T : struct
{
    _copyToManaged(source, destination, startIndex, length);
}
```

Since `Marshal` class internals can be changed, this method is unreliable and should not be used, though this implementation is probably the closest to other `Marshal.Copy()` method overloads.

Comment: You should used `fixed` when converting the array to a pointer

Comment: `fixed` cannot be used to create a generic `Copy<T>()` method because `fixed(T* ptr = array)` would not compile. There is no generic constraint to allow that. Also `fixed` requires `unsafe` option, while using `GCHandle` does not.

Comment: Great answers. Any intuition as the the ranking in order of performance? [Not that I do this conversion to managed space in normal mode, but for debug it is useful to divert the 25 fps traffic to the host, instead of sending it to the GPU for processing).

Comment: Performance of all those options should be similar. My bet - `CopyMemory()` is the fastest, but you should definitely test that.

Comment: The `length` parameter of `CopyMemory` should be of type `uint`, not `UIntPtr`! Otherwise, the signature will be incorrect on 64-bit platforms

Answer (score 1):

In modern .NET, you might be able to work in terms of spans instead of arrays, then things become interesting:

```cs
public unsafe Span<ushort> bits()
    => new Span<short>(rawbits.ToPointer(), width * height);
```

This is zero copy, but does *not* propagate the `unsafe` - consumers can access the span in managed / "safe" code. It works much like an array, include bounds elision etc - but can talk to unmanaged memory.

You can use `ReadOnlySpan<T>` if the caller doesn't need to (or shouldn't) change the values.

Note: if you construct a span using `unsafe` and get things wrong (the length, for example), then it can still explode on the caller, hence the "safe" rather than safe.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're stuck with either doing the extra conversion yourself (short[] to ushort[], the one you basically do already), or doing the mem copy yourself through unsafe keyword.

There's third option: create custom struct.

```
struct MyMagicalStruct
{
    // todo: set SizeConst correct
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=width*height)] 
    public ushort[] Test123;
}
```

You'd also have to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyMagicalStruct>(yourPtr)`..